# Incompatible pointer type with mysql_store_result

Tags: mysql, sql, c, pointers

I am new to C but I am currently working on a project where I have a compiler warning but I can't see what the problem is, or how I am able to fix it.

I am performing a mysql query and then storing the result but when I try I fetch the row to store in the MYSQL_ROW I get the following compilation warning

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Below is how I am running the query and storing the result

```
int processDrilldownData(char **reportParameterArray, FILE *csvFile, char *sql, MYSQL *HandleDB, MYSQL_RES *resultReport, MYSQL_ROW rowReport, int UserLevel, int ParentUserLevel, char *CustomerDisplayName, Restrictions *reportRestrictions, int totalLookupNumberCount, numberLookupStruct *numberLookup, int maximumLookupChars, char * statsOutputTable, int targetNumber, FILE * sqlDebugFile)
        {
        MYSQL_RES * audioResult = NULL;
            MYSQL_ROW * audioRow = NULL;
        sqlLen = asprintf(&sql, "SELECT Tmp.SwitchID, Tmp.CorrelationID, SUM(IF(Direction=2,1,0)) as SSPAudio, "
                "SUM(IF(Direction=1,Duration/100,0)) as SSPAudioDur FROM %s AS Tmp GROUP BY Tmp.SwitchID, "
                "Tmp.CorrelationID ORDER BY Tmp.SwitchID, Tmp.CorrelationID, Direction, SeizeUTC, SeizeCSec",
                statsOutputTable);
        if ((mysql_real_query(HandleDB, sql, sqlLen))) return 1;

            audioResult = mysql_store_result(HandleDB);

    audioRow = mysql_fetch_row(audioResult);
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is from [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-fetch-row.html) and not `mysql_store_result()`. `mysql_fetch_row` returns `MYSQL_ROW`, note the missing `*`.

So the declaration must look like

```
MYSQL_ROW audioRow;
```